# How to upload a file (specifically images) from HTML to my database?

Tags: angular, image, input, file-upload, nestjs

I wanted to make a way to add new products to my database through the web app itself, so with bootstrap's help I made a modal for every section I made so far. It asks for the needed info including an image of the product. So, I used an input tag of file type.

```
<input type="file" accept=".png, .jpeg, .jpg" [(ngModel)]="image" class="form-control mt-3">
```

[I get this error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7whE4.png)

I used the `[(ngModel)]=...` to add the info to the database. I use NestJS and PostgreSQl in the backend.

food.component.ts:

```
postFood() {
    if (this.sale == false) {
      this.saleVal = 0
    }
    if (this.saleVal == 0) {
      this.sale = false
    }
    const product: Product = {
      name: this.name,
      price: this.price,
      description: this.description,
      category: this.category,
      sale: this.sale,
      image: this.image,
      genre: this.genre,
      saleval: this.saleVal
    }
    this.productsService.postFood(product)
  }
```

products.service.ts:

```
postFood(product: Product) {
    console.log('Food is added successfully to database!')
    return this.http.post('http://localhost:3000/food', product)
  }
```

food.controller.ts:

```
@Post()
    async create(@Body() product: Product): Promise<any> {
        return this.productsService.create(product);
    }
```

backend's service (products.service.ts):

```
async create(product: Product): Promise<any> {
        return await this.productsRepository.save(product);
    }
```

I tried adding input field of type file. I expected it sending the image as a string of the image's path to the database, but I got an error while uploading it.

Comment: You need to use Multer + File Interceptor in Nest: https://docs.nestjs.com/techniques/file-upload You'll need to use a multi-part POST/PUT call from Angular to add the file data to the request

Comment: This seems like a new topic to learn.

Comment: Nest actually makes it pretty easy for you